# Learn Python the Hard Way Ex 25: local variable/object assignment in functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning the basics of python2 by studying Zed Shaw's book "Learn Python The Hard Way". On exercise 25 the author gives a few functions, like:

```
def break_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    return words

def print_first_word(words):
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word
```

I shortened the functions like this:

```
def break_words(sentence):
    return sentence.split(' ')

def print_first_word(sentence)
    print break_words(sentence).pop(0)
```

And wanted to know if there is a reason the author assigns .split() & .pop() to words/word?

Thank you

Comment: Only for clarity.

Comment: Why on earth are you learning Python 2? It will reach its official End of Life in 2020. You should be learning Python 3. And then you can learn Python 2 if you need it to work on (or read) legacy code.

Comment: @PM2Ring because the author suggests to first learn Python 2 ... you got me confused and frustrated with this one :)

Comment: That advice may have been good several years ago, but it doesn't make much sense these days: it's like telling someone who can't speak English that they should first learn Shakespeare's English.

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. And we aren't very impressed with Zed's severe anti-Python 3 stance in that book. FWIW, he has now done a Python 3 version, but he's still not a big fan of Python 3.

Comment: Note that the original will leave you with a shortened `words` list, while your version will always discard the rest of the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only reason is for ***readability*** (in their view).

For many just `returning` them directly would be just as clear, but it is up to whoever is writing the code or whoever the code is being wrote for.

Your method of shortening them is what I personally would go with, but it is a matter of preference.

Taking guidance from [`the ZEN of Python`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> **The Zen of Python**
>   `Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   Readability counts.
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>   Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`

As a sidenote, there is an easter-egg whereby this is `printed` to the console by running: `import this`.